# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory when connect to Amazon RDS

Tags: php, sql, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-rds

I'm hosting my web application to AWS using Amazon RDS MySQL for the database and Amazon EC2 for the server.

I have changed the database config (I'm using CodeIgniter) like this:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysql:hostname=my-rds-endpoint.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com; dbname=go-edang; charset=utf8;',
    'username' => 'my-username',
    'password' => 'my-password',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

When I access the URL by using the DNS from my EC2 instance, it goes like this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/Login.php

Line Number: 7
```

Is there any file or line that I should change? Or what is the correct way? Thank you.

Comment: don't share your credentials in public.

Comment: whats there in `Login.php` line `7` post the code

Comment: @AbdullaNilam yeah, i've changed the endpoint as well. `Login.php` line 7 is just `parent::__construct();`

Comment: the hostname can't be found. The hostname should be my-rds-endpoint.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com only. What you put there looks more like a DSN. ANother point - ad your port 3306

Comment: @jtwes it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this config :

```php
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:hostname=my-rds-endpoint.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com; dbname=go-edang; charset=utf8;', 
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'my-username',
    'password' => 'my-password',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```